# How to declare global variables in android application?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to declare global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

How to declare global variables in android application?

Comment: What do you mean by "global variable"?  It would help if you could explain what you want to store in the variable and from where you want to reference it.

Comment: Look at this topic [Android: How to declare global variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

you can use static keyword for global variable...

Answer (score 0):

Declare object in class which extends from [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class